# Accessing session of spring injected EntityManager

Tags: spring, session, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

In my application, i have injected EntityManager through Spring. How can i access EntityManager session? When i tried to do this:

```
Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) entityManager).getActiveSession();
```

I get casting exception, as spring injects a proxy for entityManager. Please let me know how to do this.

Note: I'm using Eclipselink JPA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [unwrap](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29) method of EntityManager to access the provider-specific implementation.

PS: I've not found any EntityManagerImpl in EclipseLink javadoc. Where is it?

Comment: I got this when browsing for such code... eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105968/eclipselink-document-doesnt-explain-session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unwrap` as suggested by @JBNizet.  However that requires that you be using JPA 2.0 compliant API.  If however you are constrained to use JPA 1.0 try the [JpaHelper class](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/1.0/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/JpaHelper.html).  Its `getEntityManager` method can be used to get at the active session.

```
JpaHelper.getEntityManager(entityManager).getActiveSession()
```

Comment: I'm using JPA 2.0 implementation. Thanks.